# Timer already cancelled

Tags: java, multithreading, timer, timertask

I have two timers to manage input(en-queue) and output (dequeue) from a FIFO queue but I keep getting a exception for the dequeueing java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled. I can't place a stop to debug line where the error is claimed to occur line 83. I don't know what I'm missing so any help would be appreciated.

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Timer;
import java.util.TimerTask;

/**
 * RunSim
 */
public class RunSim {
    private double arrivalRate = 600;
    private double y;
    private Timer t;
    private Timer t2;
    private Queue fifoQueue;
    private long xy;
    private long fact = 10;
    private int count;
    private int pId;

    public RunSim() {
        Random r = new Random();
        long n = System.currentTimeMillis();
        r.setSeed(n);
        double i = r.nextDouble();
        y = ((1 / arrivalRate) * (Math.log(i)));
        xy = (long) y;
        t = new Timer();
        t2 = new Timer();
        fifoQueue = new Queue();
        count = 0;
        pId = 0;

    }

    public static void main() {
        RunSim rs = new RunSim();
        rs.start();
    }

    public void start() {
        class sendPacket extends TimerTask {
            public void run() {
                Packet p = new Packet();
                p.setId(pId);
                fifoQueue.insert(p);
                p.setArrivalTime();
                System.out.println("ID: " + p.getId() + " Arrival Time: "
                        + p.getArrivalTime() / fact);
                pId++;

            }
        }

        class removePacket extends TimerTask {
            public void run() {
                fifoQueue.first().setDepartureTime();
                System.out.println("ID: " + fifoQueue.first().getId()
                        + " Departure Time: "
                        + fifoQueue.first().getDepartureTime() / fact);
                fifoQueue.remove();
            }
        }

        while (count < 1000) {
            long v = fact * (1 + Math.abs(xy));
            t.schedule(new sendPacket(), 0, v);
            count++;
            t2.schedule(new removePacket(), 5, 5);

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: And the full stack trace of the exception is...? And line 83 is... ?

Comment: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
 at java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:354)
 at java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:222)
 at RunSim.start(RunSim.java:83)
 at RunSim.main(RunSim.java:47)


Line 83: t2.schedule(new removePacket(),5,5);

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Immediately after scheduling all the timers, you cancel them. This doesn't work like the `ExecutorService` where you can schedule all you need and then call `shutdown`—this actually cancels the timer and all scheduled tasks.

Another problem with your code is that you call `System.exit` right away, not giving any chance to the scheduled tasks to actually run.

Apart from those problems, you may get a `Timer already canceled` exception if a previous task threw an exception. The exception will not be seen anywhere, but it will cancel the timer. Be sure to wrap your timer tasks into a catch-all try-statement.

Comment: Even when I didn't have those lines timer t2 would mysteriously cancel. But i'll remove them.

Comment: The point about wrapping a task in a catch-all block is crucial. The Timer documentation refers to this (elliptically, IMO) by saying: "If the timer's task execution thread terminates unexpectedly, for example, because its stop method is invoked, any further attempt to schedule a task on the timer will result in an IllegalStateException, as if the timer's cancel method had been invoked." The key bit being "terminates unexpectedly"...